# I cannot find iOS simulator in my mac

Tags: .app

I cannot find iOS simulator on my mac.

I am using snow leopard, and I recently installed Xcode through the applications DVD. When I go into Developer/Platforms, apparently iOS simulator.platform should be there. But there is only a folder called MacOSX.platforms. There is a few plist files there, and one folder. Inside this folder, called Developer, iOS simulator.app is not there. This folder contains many subfolders, but none contain the application.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the XCode version on the applications DVD does not include the iOS tools. You can download the latest version of XCode here:

http://developer.apple.com/xcode/index.php

Answer (score 0):

At the point that DVD was made, I think you still needed to download Xcode from Apple to get the iOS SDK. Just grab Xcode 4 from the App Store (on Snow Leopard, that'll set you back the princely sum of $5. Upgrade to Lion, it's free). You can also get 3.2.6 for free from Apple's developer site (register for a free developer account), but the bundled iOS SDK is so far out of date, it's worthless.